# I got some error while installing wordcloud

Tags: python, macos, gcc, terminal, cython

I tried to install the wordcloud but I got some problem, I have latest version of OS X yosemite and GCC.

As in the message below it's a problem in GCC and cython, this is what on terminal appears:

```
idomyoung@idomyeongs-MacBook-Pro:~$ sudo pip install wordcloud
Password:
The directory '/Users/idomyoung/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/idomyoung/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting wordcloud
  Downloading wordcloud-1.2.tar.gz (162kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 115kB/s 
Installing collected packages: wordcloud
  Running setup.py install for wordcloud
    Complete output from command /Users/idomyoung/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-h0FZer/wordcloud/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-56Yo14-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud
    copying wordcloud/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud
    copying wordcloud/color_from_image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud
    copying wordcloud/wordcloud.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud
    copying wordcloud/stopwords -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud
    copying wordcloud/DroidSansMono.ttf -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud
    running build_ext
    building 'wordcloud.query_integral_image' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/idomyoung/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/idomyoung/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c wordcloud/query_integral_image.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud/query_integral_image.o
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:16230:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject* __Pyx_PyUnicode_FromString(const char* c_str) {
                                   ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:302:29: warning: unused function '__Pyx_Py_UNICODE_strlen' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE size_t __Pyx_Py_UNICODE_strlen(const Py_UNICODE *u)
                                ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:16370:33: warning: unused function '__Pyx_PyInt_FromSize_t' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject * __Pyx_PyInt_FromSize_t(size_t ival) {
                                    ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:14326:26: warning: unused function '__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE int __Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate(
                             ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:14360:27: warning: unused function '__Pyx_SafeReleaseBuffer' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE void __Pyx_SafeReleaseBuffer(Py_buffer* info) {
                              ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:14433:1: warning: unused function '__pyx_add_acquisition_count_locked' [-Wunused-function]
    __pyx_add_acquisition_count_locked(__pyx_atomic_int *acquisition_count,
    ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:14443:1: warning: unused function '__pyx_sub_acquisition_count_locked' [-Wunused-function]
    __pyx_sub_acquisition_count_locked(__pyx_atomic_int *acquisition_count,
    ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:15021:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_GetItemInt_List_Fast' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__Pyx_GetItemInt_List_Fast(PyObject *o, Py_ssize_t i,
                                   ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:15035:32: warning: unused function '__Pyx_GetItemInt_Tuple_Fast' [-Wunused-function]
    static CYTHON_INLINE PyObject *__Pyx_GetItemInt_Tuple_Fast(PyObject *o, Py_ssize_t i,
                                   ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:15995:27: warning: function '__Pyx_PyInt_As_char' is not needed and will not be emitted [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]
    static CYTHON_INLINE char __Pyx_PyInt_As_char(PyObject *x) {
                              ^
    wordcloud/query_integral_image.c:16090:27: warning: function '__Pyx_PyInt_As_long' is not needed and will not be emitted [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]
    static CYTHON_INLINE long __Pyx_PyInt_As_long(PyObject *x) {
                              ^
    11 warnings generated.
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/idomyoung/anaconda/lib -arch x86_64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud/query_integral_image.o -L/Users/idomyoung/anaconda/lib -o build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/wordcloud/query_integral_image.so
    ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/idomyoung/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-h0FZer/wordcloud/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-56Yo14-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-h0FZer/wordcloud
```